# Javascript: Get diagonal array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently trying to get the diagonal row of a two dimensional array.

This is how the array looks like:

```
/*    Array containing the playing field 8 x 8 

       C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
    R0[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][X]
    R1[0][0][0][0][0][0][X][0]
    R2[0][0][0][0][0][X][0][0] 
    R3[0][0][0][0][X][0][0][0] 
    R4[0][0][0][X][0][0][0][0]
    R5[0][0][X][0][0][0][0][0] 
    R6[0][X][0][0][0][0][0][0] 
    R7[X][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
*/

    row0 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row6 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row7 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    field = [row0, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7];
```

I am trying to check if a player of the game has four in a row. The function currently handling the horizontal and vertical check gets the following information:

The column id and the row id the user clicked (x in the function represents the player number)

This is the function I use to check:

```
function checkVieropeenrij(id, rij, x) {
    function contains(hooibaal, naalden) {
        return hooibaal.join(",").indexOf(naalden.join(",")) != -1;
    }

    var horizontaal = field[0, rij];
    var verticaal = [];
       for (g=7; g>=0; g--) {

            verticaal[g] = field[g][id-1]

       }

    var diagonaal = []


    var needles = [x, x, x, x];

    if (contains(horizontaal, needles) || contains(verticaal, needles)) {
        spelActief = false;
        return true
    }

    else if (!contains(horizontaal, needles) || !contains(verticaal, needles)) {
        return false
    } 
}
```

So what I want to do is store the [X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X] in a new array (variable diagonaal_1) and I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this.

The place of the diagonal depends on the place the player clicked, so if they click on C6,R6 it should get diagonal from R7,C5 to R0,C7 and diagonal R7,C7 to R0,C0 (both diagonals across the playing field stored in seperate vars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proposal moves the given position to the relative top of the array and collect the items in the given direction.

Basically it checks first, if there is space to move and while collecting, is space to collect.

```js
var height = 8,
    width = 8,
    field = [
        [0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
        [0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
        [4, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];

function getBackSlash(i, j) {             // direction \
    var result = [];
    while (i > 0 && j > 0) {              // is space to move (top/left)?
        i--;
        j--;
    }
    while (i < height && j < width) {     // are items in the range to collect?
        result.push(field[i][j]);
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    return result;
}

function getSlash(i, j) {                 // direction /
    var result = [];
    while (i > 0 && j + 1 < width) {      // is space to move (top/right)?
        i--;
        j++;
    }
    while (i < height && j >= 0) {        // are items in the range to collect?
        result.push(field[i][j]);
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return result;
}

document.write('<pre>1: [' + getBackSlash(3, 4).join(', ') + ']</pre>');
document.write('<pre>2: [' + getBackSlash(7, 2).join(', ') + ']</pre>');
document.write('<pre>3: [' + getSlash(3, 3).join(', ') + ']</pre>');
document.write('<pre>4: [' + getSlash(0, 2).join(', ') + ']</pre>');
```